# Create a new tibble using the previous row value of a column as a parameter of the current row value

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to manually create a tibble where one column values are calculated depending on the previous value of the same column.

For example:

```
tibble(
  x = 1:5,
  y = x + lag(y, default = 0)
)
```

I expect the following result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      x     y
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     3
3     3     6
4     4    10
5     5    15
```

But I obtain the error:

```
Error in lag(y, default = 0) : object 'y' not found
```

**Update - more real example:**

```
tibble(
  years = 1:5,
  salary = 20000 * (1.01) ^ lag(years, default = 0),
  qta = salary * 0.06
) %>%
  mutate(
    total = ifelse(row_number() == 1,
                   (qta + 50000) * (1.02),
                   (qta + lag(total, default = 0)) * (1.02))
  )
```

In this example I have a tibble, and I want to add a column 'total' that is defined depending on its previous value, but the `lag(total, default = 0)` doesn't work.

Comment: you didn't define y before putting it into the `lag` function. Did you mean to put `x` there?

Comment: No, it's correct. I want y to be defined in function of y itself.

Comment: Can you please update with a more general example

Comment: Added. I hope now it's more clear. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `accumulate`

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x = 1:5, y = accumulate(x, `+`))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#      x     y
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     1
#2     2     3
#3     3     6
#4     4    10
#5     5    15
```

For a general function, it would be

```
tibble(x = 1:5, y = accumulate(x, ~ .x + .y))
```

We can also specify the initialization value

```
tibble(x = 1:5, y = accumulate(x[-1], ~ .x + .y, .init = x[1]))
```

Comment: I don't need the cumulative sum of x, forget about x. I only need to define y in function of its previous value

Comment: @RaulS.  What is the issue with using `mutate`, it can take any functions.  Note that `x + lag(x, default = 0)` is not matching with the expected output

Comment: @RaulS.  If the calculation is based on previous values, use `accumulate`

Comment: Sorry for my comment, I misread your example. However I can't figure out how to use ```accumulate``` in my case. Please take a look to the updated example

Comment: Ok.. I got it:
```tibble(
  years = 1:5,
  salary = 20000 * (1.01) ^ lag(years, default = 0),
  qta = salary * 0.06
) %>%
  mutate(
    total = accumulate(qta[-1], ~ (.x + .y) * 1.02, .init = qta[1] + 50000)
  )```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing x instead of y in the lag() function to run without an error:

```
tibble(
 x = 1:5,
 y = x + lag(x, default = 0)
)
```

But as per @Ronak Shah's comment, you need the cumsum() function to get the same result as your example:

```
tibble(
 x = 1:5, 
 y = cumsum(x)
)
```

Comment: This is only an example, but I need to defilne y in funcion of the previous valute of y itself. I don't think cumsum help me.